# Shorter way to call specific plugin function

Tags: command-line, autocompletion

In the middle of a Vim session, I need to call a particular plugin's function via:

```
:call UltiSnips#RefreshSnippets()
```

When from normal mode I type `:call UltiS<Tab>`, it auto-expands to alphabetically the first offered function:

```
:call UltiSnips#AddFiletypes(
```

From here, I have to delete backward one character at a time until the `#` and then press `R<tab>` to get autocompletion to have:

```
:call UltiSnips#RefreshSnippets()
```

Is there any quicker way to delete backward until the `#` instead of backspace multiple times? Or else, is there a way to just:

```
:call UltiS<do something>
```

to get directly to:

```
:call UltiSnips#RefreshSnippets()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command mode you can use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

It delete the previous 'word'

Comment: I see that this is similar to insert mode as well. Ctrlu, likewise, deletes everything and leaves only `:`. Thx!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-). You have also Ctrl-h to delete the previous character. Ctrl-d for suggestion of completion.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> (`:help 'cedit'`) and `T#C` or similar. Or make a custom command or mapping that calls the function.